# open a form from current directory

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

How can I open a form stored in the current directory

```
do form ADDBS( JUSTPATH(SYS(16,0))) +"\form5.scx" WITH thisform.grid1.Column1.Text1.Value TO aa
```

I tried this but says that the file doesn't exist

Comment: If it's the current directory, you don't need a path at all. Just DO FORM form5.scx ...

Answer (score 1):

```
do form form5 with ...
```

VFP uses relative pathing and also search paths. If it is in current directory then would be the first one to be picked by VFP.

Comment: I tried what you said but doesn't work, gives me this error "file 'C:\Users\ama\Documents\Visual FoxPro Projects\form5.scx' doesn't exist"

Comment: Well it works since day 1 of foxpro and it still works. In your case, it means that there isn't a Form5.scx in the current folder. Does it really exists in  "C:\Users\ama\Documents\Visual FoxPro Projects"? That is a strange location to put a form anyway. Instead maybe you should try it with: do form (locfile("form5.scx")) with ...

Comment: My form5.scx are located in current folder. I have form1.scx and form5.scx, which are located both in C:\Users\ama\Desktop\New folder and I'm trying to access form5 from form1.

Comment: What is your "current folder"? Check typing CD [enter] at command prompt. You can explicitly set your current folder and retry: set default to "C:\Users\ama\Desktop\New folder". Or you can use locfile() as I said.

Answer (score 0):

ADDBS( JUSTPATH(SYS(16,0)))
this adds already a slash ("\") to the path and you add another slash with "\form5.scx"
can do 
do form ADDBS( JUSTPATH(SYS(16,0)))+"form5.scx"

or use relative path or locfile() function

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. VFP would treat the path same. The only difference is that, if justpath( sys(16,0) ) returns an empty string, then \form5.scx would have a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

to test what i said copy this code and execute it: you can see there is 2 "\"
addbs() works only on what its applied not in the second independent term of the path.

```
local m.myvar
text to m.myvar noshow
messagebox(ADDBS( JUSTPATH(SYS(16,0))) +"\form5.scx")
_cliptext=ADDBS( JUSTPATH(SYS(16,0))) +"\form5.scx"
endtext
```

strtofile(m.myvar,"test.prg")

do test